# Unable to run Jupyter Notebook plus TensorFlow in Virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, virtualenv, jupyter-notebook

I Have followed the steps on [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac#the_url_of_the_tensorflow_python_package) as descrived and was able Activate 
`source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate` and installed
`(tensorflow)$ pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow` everthing worked out fine and i was able to run the tensorflow **Hello World** program.

I looked my local jupyter path

```
(tensorflow)username$ which jupyter
(tensorflow)username$/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/jupyter
```

Then I tried to install jupyter on tensorflow Virtualenv

```
(tensorflow) username$ pip3 install jupyter
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: ipywidgets in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from jupyter)
.....................
.....................
```

Then I deactivated the virtual environment and restarted my terminal and again activated tensorflow. I tried to double check my path on the virtualenv. Got the same thing again.

```
(tensorflow)username$ which jupyter
(tensorflow)username$/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/jupyter
```

I tried all the blogs solutions including `pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL`

Now when even I run Hello World in Jupyter notebook I get [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDbTN.png)

Comment: so what's wrong?

Comment: Upon failing to use virtualenv with jupyter notebook, i installed tensorflow and keras locally, now jupyter notebook able to locate the libraries.